# Stripe Subscription adding same card twice

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I have implemented Stripe Subscription with the following steps :

1. Add card via Stripe Elements using stripe.PaymentMethod.attach :

   ```
               stripe_customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(str(customer.stripe_customer_id))
               payment_methods_list = stripe.PaymentMethod.list(customer=stripe_customer.id, type="card")

               card = request.data['card']
                   stripe_paymentmethod_id = card['id']

               stripe.PaymentMethod.attach( stripe_paymentmethod_id, customer=stripe_customer.id)
               stripe.Customer.modify(
                   stripe_customer.id,
                   invoice_settings={
                       "custom_fields": None,
                       "default_payment_method": stripe_paymentmethod_id,
                       "footer": None,
                       "rendering_options": None
                   },
               )
   ```
2. Then create a subscription, and generate a client secret :

   ```
     stripe.confirmCardPayment(resultState.data.clientsecret, {
          payment_method: {
            card: info.card_element,
            billing_details: {
              name: "Name Surname",
            },
          }
   ```
3. Then finally confirm payment card in FrontEnd :

   ```
                stripe_customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(customer.stripe_customer_id)
                stripe_subscription_list = stripe.Subscription.list(customer=customer.stripe_customer_id)
                stripe_subscription_list_len = len(stripe_subscription_list.data)
                stripe_subscription = None
                if stripe_subscription_list_len != 0:
                    stripe_subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(stripe_subscription_list.data[0].id)

                if ((stripe_subscription_list_len == 0) or (stripe_subscription_list_len == 1)) and \
                    (selected_product.plan == 0 and customer.product.plan != selected_product.plan) or \
                    (selected_product.plan > 0 and stripe_customer.invoice_settings.default_payment_method != None and customer.product.plan != selected_product.plan):
                    logging.info(f"SubscriptionCreate post Subscription Modify.")
                    logging.info(f"stripe_customer.invoice_settings.default_payment_method : {stripe_customer.invoice_settings.default_payment_method}")
                    logging.info(f"SubscriptionCreate customer.product.plan : {customer.product.plan}")
                    logging.info(f"SubscriptionCreate selected_product.plan : {selected_product.plan}")

                    # This will be removed in deployment
                    logging.info(f"SubscriptionCreate Deleting Free Plan : {selected_product.plan}")
                    if stripe_subscription:
                        stripe.Subscription.delete(stripe_subscription.id)
                    logging.info(f"SubscriptionCreate Free Plan Deleted : {selected_product.plan}")

                    new_subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
                        customer=customer.stripe_customer_id,
                        items=[{"price": stripe_product.stripe_plan_id},],
                        payment_behavior='default_incomplete',
                        payment_settings={'save_default_payment_method': 'on_subscription'},
                        expand=['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
                    )
                    if new_subscription:
                            customer.product = stripe_product
                            customer.active = False
                            if customer.product.plan == 0:
                                customer.active = True
                            logging.info(f"stripe_subscription_list new_subscription : {new_subscription}")
                            customer.clientsecret = new_subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret
                            customer.stripe_subscription_id = new_subscription.id
                            customer.save()
                            #logging.info(f"clientSecret : {new_subscription['latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret}")

                            logging.info(f"stripe_subscription_list new_subscription clientsecret : {customer.clientsecret}")
   ```

However, in this solution, the card is being added twice as I can see in Stripe Dashboard.

The first time obviously, the card is added in here :

```
stripe.PaymentMethod.attach( stripe_paymentmethod_id, customer=stripe_customer.id)
```

But if I remove "stripe.PaymentMethod.attach" then subscription create does not generate client secret for the frontend.

How can I avoid the card being added twice under any circumstances ?

Comment: I faced this issue before. To avoid the card being added twice, you can remove the "stripe.PaymentMethod.attach()" method and use the "default_payment_method" parameter in the "stripe.Customer.modify()" method to set the default payment method for the customer.

Comment: When I do that, and if there is no payment card prior to subscription create, then I get this message when I try to retireve clientsecret : "Missing value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string.", @dostogircse171, your suggestion does not seem to work.

Comment: I think you could look into this [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements&element=card&lang=python) and rethink your approach